# List of strings to case class with inner case classes

Tags: scala, shapeless

Let's say i have 2 cases classes:

```
case class Money(amount: Int, currency: String)
case class Human(name: String, money: Money)
```

is there a nice way to "translate" a list of strings to class Human? smth like:

```
def superMethod[A](params: List[String]): A = ???

val params: List[Any] = List("john", 100, "dollar")
superMethod(params) // => Human("john", Money(100, "dollar"))
```

so essentially i know type A only in runtime

**UPDATE**: i found ~ what i was looking for. it seems i can do it via shapeless. [example](https://github.com/JakeGreene/shapeless-csv) i found in github

Comment: Can it be assumed that the `params` string is generated by the depth-first traversal of the tree of case classes? Or can the elements come in any order? Do you have all possible classes `A` under your control, or do they come from some external libraries? Is it now `List[Any]` or `List[String]`?

Comment: elements in the `params` list match exactly the case class. we can assume that params is a list of strings or any, which is more convenient for solution. the only hard requirement is that i don't know what type A exactly is, as far as I want to have `superMethod` as polymorphic one.

Comment: You will have to pass in *something*, at least an implicit `TypeTag[A]`, otherwise there is no way to find out what class should be deserialized.

Comment: IMHO, 100 is not a String. This isn't Javascript here. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an implementation that works for generic classes `A`.

It relies on runtime reflection (that is, a different `TypeTag` can be passed to the method at runtime). The following obvious conditions must be fulfilled in order to use this method:

- `A` must be on the class path, or otherwise be loadable by the used class loader
- `TypeTag` must be available for `A` at the call site.

The actual implementation is in the `Deserializer` object. Then comes a little demo.

The deserializer:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, Type}

object Deserializer {

  /** Extracts an instance of type `A` from the 
    * flattened `Any` constructor arguments, and returns 
    * the constructed instance together with the remaining
    * unused arguments.
    */
  private def deserializeRecHelper(
    flattened: List[Any], 
    tpe: Type
  ): (Any, List[Any]) = {
    import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
    
    // println("Trying to deserialize " + tpe + " from " + flattened)

    // println("Constructor alternatives: ")
    // val constructorAlternatives = tpe.
    //   member(ru.termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).
    //   asTerm.
    //   alternatives.foreach(println)

    val consSymb = tpe.
      member(ru.termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).
      asTerm.
      alternatives(0).
      asMethod

    val argsTypes: List[Type] = consSymb.paramLists(0).map(_.typeSignature)
    if (tpe =:= ru.typeOf[String] || argsTypes.isEmpty) {
      val h :: t = flattened
      (h, t)
    } else {
      val args_rems: List[(Any, List[Any])] = argsTypes.scanLeft(
        (("throwaway-sentinel-in-deserializeRecHelper": Any), flattened)
      ) { 
        case ((_, remFs), t) => 
        deserializeRecHelper(remFs, t)
      }.tail
  
      val remaining: List[Any] = args_rems.last._2
      val args: List[Any] = args_rems.unzip._1
  
      val runtimeMirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
      val classMirror = runtimeMirror.reflectClass(tpe.typeSymbol.asClass)
      val cons = classMirror.reflectConstructor(consSymb)
  
      // println("Build constructor arguments array for " + tpe + " : " + args)

      val obj = cons.apply(args:_*)
      (obj, remaining)
    }
  }

  def deserialize[A: TypeTag](flattened: List[Any]): A = {
    val (a, rem) = deserializeRecHelper(
      flattened, 
      (implicitly: TypeTag[A]).tpe
    )

    require(
      rem.isEmpty, 
      "Superfluous arguments remained after deserialization: " + rem
    )

    a.asInstanceOf[A]
  }
}
```

Demo:

```
case class Person(id: String, money: Money, pet: Pet, lifeMotto: String)
case class Money(num: Int, currency: String)
case class Pet(color: String, species: Species)
case class Species(description: String, name: String)

object Example {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val data = List("Bob", 42, "USD", "pink", "invisible", "unicorn", "what's going on ey?")
    val p = Deserializer.deserialize[Person](data)
    println(p)
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Person(Bob,Money(42,USD),Pet(pink,Species(invisible,unicorn)),what's going on ey?)
```

---

Discussion

This implementation is not restricted to case classes, but it requires each "Tree-node-like" class to have exactly one constructor that accepts either

- primitive types (Int, Float), or
- strings, or
- other "Tree-node-like" classes.

Note that the task is somewhat ill-posed: what does it mean to say that all constructor arguments are flattened in a single list? Given the class `Person(name: String, age: Int)`, will the `List[Any]` contain every single byte of the `name` as a separate entry? Probably not. Therefore, strings are handled by the deserializer in a special way, and all other collection-like entities are not supported for the same reasons (unclear where to stop parsing, because size of the collection is not known).

Answer (score 2):

In case A is not a generic type, but effectively Human, you can use a companion object to the case class Human:

```
object Human {
  def fromList(list: List[String]): Human = list match {
    case List(name, amount, currency) => Human(name, Money(amount.toInt, currency))
    case _ => handle corner case
  }
}
```

Which you can call:

```
Human.fromList(List("john", "100", "dollar"))
```

To make it safe, don't forget to handle the case of lists whose size wouldn't be 3; and of lists whose 2nd element can't be cast to an Int:

```
import scala.util.Try

object Human {
  def fromList(list: List[String]): Option[Human] = list match {
    case List(name, amount, currency) =>
      Try(Human(name, Money(amount.toInt, currency))).toOption
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

Edit: Based on your last comment, you might find this usefull:

```
case class Money(amount: Int, currency: String)
case class Human(name: String, money: Money)
case class SomethingElse(whatever: Double)

object Mapper {
  def superMethod(list: List[String]): Option[Any] =
    list match {
      case List(name, amount, currency) =>
        Try(Human(name, Money(amount.toInt, currency))).toOption
      case List(whatever) => Try(SomethingElse(whatever.toDouble)).toOption
      case _ => None
    }
}

println(Mapper.superMethod(List("john", 100, "dollar")))
> Some(Human(john,Money(100,dollar)))
println(Mapper.superMethod(List(17d)))
> Some(SomethingElse(17.0))
```

or alternatively:

```
object Mapper {
  def superMethod[A](list: List[String]): Option[A] =
    (list match {
      case List(name, amount, currency) =>
        Try(Human(name, Money(amount, currency))).toOption
      case List(whatever) =>
        Try(SomethingElse(whatever.toDouble)).toOption
      case _ => None
    }).map(_.asInstanceOf[A])
}

println(Mapper.superMethod[Human](List("john", "100", "dollar")))
> Some(Human(john,Money(100,dollar)))
println(Mapper.superMethod[SomethingElse](List("17.2")))
> Some(SomethingElse(17.0))
```

Comment: but how to approach it in case when I don't know the type at runtime? lets say class A has 15 fields, two of which are case classes as well

Comment: that is the thing - i don't want to create method `fromList` for each type i have. i could have like 10 types each with 10+ fields, so i was thinking about some polymorphic method

Comment: Do you mean for instance that `amount` could either be given as an `Int` or `String`?

Comment: I mean that Human & Monay classes were just examples. i want to have method, which receives as input list of strings and class type, which says what object should be generated: `def superMethod[A](params: List[String])`

Comment: Updated the answer; hope this helps